# php function verify token works in localhost but not on GoDaddy server

Tags: php, authentication, oauth-2.0

I have php function that is supposed to verify if there is a token, and if so, display some information. The function works fine when I use xampp in localhost. When I do it in prod on the server, it gives me a 'token undefined' error, even though I can see the token in dev tools. What could possibly be causing the error?
my php function

```
    public function viewCompanies()
    {

        if (isset($GLOBALS['headers']['Authorization'])) {
            print_r($GLOBALS['headers']['Authorization']);

            if ($id = $this->VerifyUserToken($GLOBALS['headers']['Authorization'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {

                $companies = $this->currentModel->viewCompanies();

                if ($companies) {
                    echo json_encode($companies);

                } else {
                    echo json_encode(['success' => false]);
                }

            }
            else {
                echo json_encode(['success' => false, 'error' => "invalid token"]);
            }

        } else {
            echo json_encode(['success' => false, 'error' => "token undefined"]);
        }


    }
```

the verifyUserToken function

```
public function verifyUserToken($token, $ip) {
        $db = new Database();

        $db->query('SELECT * FROM auth WHERE token = :token AND expiry >now()');

        $db->bind(':token', $token);
        //check database if token exists and is not expired
        if($res = $db->single()) {
            // checks if token matches to ip address
            // returns user or contact id if verified else returns false
            if($res->token === $token && $res->ip === $ip) {
                $this->cleanTokens();
                if($res->user_id >0) {
                    return $res->user_id;
                }
//              
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

I checked the database, and the token is clearly there

I tested the function on Postman and I get the same token undefined error. Please let me know if there's any other info I should add. I've no idea how to debug this.

Comment: you say "I can see the token in dev tools", but that is just what the browser sends. IE you should check what the server receives, try print_r or returning $GLOBALS['headers']['Authorization'] and $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']

Answer (score 0):

in the end. it was goDaddy that saved the day. They sent me the following message, after I opened a ticket and spoke with them:
In regards to the issue you are seeing with custom HTTP headers being stripped out of requests on your site, the issue you are running into is actually due to the CGI handler Apache is configured to use by default on cPanel. The CGI handler, for security reasons, strips out custom header entries that are not explicitly registered within Apache's configuration. We can further verify this by changing the PHP handler the site uses from CGI to PHP-FPM.
If you...please do not hesitate to contact our support teams over the phone or through live chat.

Sincerely,

all's well that ends well.